# GridView Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, gridview, drop-down-menu

have a gridview with template fields, one column contains a dropdownlist that should be populated with a sql statement. I have created the grid dynamically and called the rowdatabound in order to access the dropdownlist but I keep recieving the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Anyone have any ideas?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField EditText="Add" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />                          
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>        
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" />        
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>        
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" />        
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is the code for the creation of the GridView Dynamically, this is done in the page_load event:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim CommittedTable As New DataTable("Committed")

        CommittedTable.Columns.Add("Date Posted", GetType(Date))
        CommittedTable.Columns.Add("Vendor", GetType(String))
        CommittedTable.Columns.Add("Expense Description", GetType(String))
        CommittedTable.Columns.Add("Ledger", GetType(String))
        CommittedTable.Columns.Add("Amount", GetType(String))
        CommittedTable.Columns.Add("Initials", GetType(String))

        For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count
            Dim tableRow As DataRow = CommittedTable.NewRow()

            tableRow("Date Posted") = Date.Today
            tableRow("Vendor") = ""
            tableRow("Expense Description") = ""
            tableRow("Ledger") = ""
            tableRow("Amount") = ""
            tableRow("Initials") = ""
            CommittedTable.Rows.Add(tableRow)
        Next

        Session("CommsTable") = CommittedTable
        BindDataComm()

    End If
```

Lastly this is the RowDataBound event handler code:

```
Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList)
    If ddl Is Nothing Then
        result = dbConnect(dbType.SqlServer, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SQLServerConnection"))
        If result = "Successful" Then
            dt = FillDataTable(dbType.SqlServer, "SELECT V_VendorNo + ' | ' + V_VendorName FROM VendorTbl")
            ddl.DataSource = dt 'it errors out here'
            ddl.DataTextField = "V_VendorNo"
            ddl.DataValueField = "V_VendorName"
            ddl.DataBind()
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: `If ddl Is Nothing Then`, is this a typing mistake? , seeing your code this should be `If ddl IsNot Nothing Then`

Comment: @Steve no it's not a tryping error if I put it as If ddl IsNot Nothing it skips everything in between and goes directly to the End If.

Comment: Then you get the 'Object reference error' when you try Nothing.DataSource = dt.

Comment: I see... any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: Not sure, the code seems right. Try to put this line before the FindControl line `if e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow then ` and of course reverse the `Is Nothing` in `IsNot Nothing`

Comment: Yea that didn't work either, it skipped over everything this time. I don't get it.

Comment: But do you have any row in your grid? And, if yes, where do you bind the gridview to your data?

Comment: There isn't a row until the user clicks the edit button. then a row appears with an update, delete button and then there are textboxes and dropdownlists

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking the RowType for Datarow before binding the Data in RowDatabound event if not Please check it....

Comment: Yes i am. I check for the rowtype first and then it goes striaght to the end if

Comment: Then please check if you are getting the datatable filled i.e.(Datatable.rows.count should be >0)..this might be giving u problem...